# How to implement common bootstrap modal in C#.Net MVC 4

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I want to use a popup on which, there will be 2 cascaded Drop-down lists & a datatable.
1st dropdown is for client selection and 2nd dropdown is of brand selection (which is based on client selection). Depending on the combination user will select one Estimate from datatable.(This is selection process)

If estimate is selected then only data from that estimate will be shown to user.
If estimate is not selected then user must go through the selection process and select one estimate.

Estimate selection will be checked on multiple pages. that's why I am using Pop-Up where I'll ask user to select one estimate.

Comment: What you means by popup, Is it window or in-page modal like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/ ?

Comment: Break the problem down into steps and implement each one. Ask a question if you actually get stuck with anything. So far you haven't actually asked us a question (just stated your intent) and the scope is too broad and vague anyway.

Comment: @Adrian Popup means Bootstrap modal in this. on which I have to show the dropdnows and datatable

Comment: @ADyson What I did is I have created a new View   In controller. which get checked before every action. If no estimate is selected then user gets redirected to new page. Where he selects estimate, Ideally after completing selection process he should be redirected automatically on the page where he was asked to perform but this is not happening for this i have already tried for Request.UrlReferrer. but that didn't worked out due to partial views i used. that's why i decided to load that entire selection process in Bootstrap modal. After lots of try I asked this question .

Comment: well firstly it's still not actually a question, it's not clear precisely what the issue is, and secondly we can only fix code, not descriptions of code